# Android Shared Preferences Crashes

Tags: java, android

This activity crashes when I put it in my phone to debug, I just added the parts for storing variables. Did I do something wrong?

It's an activity and is supposed to get the current variables if they set them earlier, and the user can also set them.

```
package com.software.roux.diabcalc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import static com.software.roux.diabcalc.R.id.bolus;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("label", 0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        setTitle("Insulin Calculator by Ben Roux");

        String bolusString = mPrefs.getString("bolus", "0");
        String corrString = mPrefs.getString("correction", "0");
        String lowString = mPrefs.getString("low", "0");
        String highString = mPrefs.getString("high", "0");

        EditText b1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bolus);
        b1.setText(bolusString);

        EditText b2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.correction);
        b2.setText(corrString);

        EditText b3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.targetlow);
        b3.setText(lowString);

        EditText b4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.targethigh);
        b4.setText(highString);
    }

    public void switchclick(View a) {
        if (a.getId() == R.id.backbutton) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, MainActivity.class);
            Settings.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }

    public void setclick(View b) {
        if (b.getId() == R.id.setter) {

            EditText b1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bolus);
            String bolussave = ""+b1;
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor1 = mPrefs.edit();
            mEditor1.putString("bolus", bolussave).commit();

            EditText b2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.correction);
            String corrsave = ""+b2;
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor2 = mPrefs.edit();
            mEditor2.putString("correction", corrsave).commit();


            EditText b3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.targetlow);
            String lowsave = ""+b3;
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor3 = mPrefs.edit();
            mEditor3.putString("low", lowsave).commit();


            EditText b4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.targethigh);
            String highsave = ""+b4;
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor4 = mPrefs.edit();
            mEditor4.putString("high", highsave).commit();


        }
    }
}
```

UPDATES CRASH LOG:

> 03-18 15:29:59.477 7801-7801/com.software.roux.diabcalc
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.software.roux.diabcalc, PID: 7801
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.software.roux.diabcalc/com.software.roux.diabcalc.Settings}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.SharedPreferences
>   android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.SharedPreferences
>   android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:185)
>                                                                                 at com.software.roux.diabcalc.Settings.(Settings.java:21)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1095)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3084)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Can you provide the crash log please?

Comment: Where would they be? Using android studio.

Comment: If you are running your program on a connected device or emulator you can see the log in the logcat. Search your Android Studio bottom bar for "Android Monitor".

Comment: Where did you put your "bolus", "correction", "low" strings ? In any other activity ? Because you are trying to getString before putString here. Thats why your app is crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initate  `SharedPreferences mPrefs` later. In `onCreate` method.

the `context` is initialized only after `onCreate` method.
So, this have to work:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        setTitle("Insulin Calculator by Ben Roux");
 mPrefs= getSharedPreferences("label", 0);
```

As the other question, in your current code you just saves address of `EditText` variable in the memory. To retrive the text, use this:

`String bolussave = ""+b1.getText().toString();`

Comment: I fixed that and now I have a seperate issue. Initially the variables are 0, but after I set them, close the app, and re-open it, they display "android.support.v7.widget...app:id/targethigh" is this the reference id and not the value? And how would i convert to the actual value?

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating your mPrefs inside your OnCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    setTitle("Insulin Calculator by Ben Roux");

    String bolusString = mPrefs.getString("bolus", "0");
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("label", 0);
    ...
    ...
```